# Getting single PID from pgrep

Tags: linux, grep, ksh

When I execute the following command on shell it returns the expected PID of e.g. 4676:

```
pgrep -f konakart
```

But when using that line on a script it returns two IDs (the expected one, and I guess the other one from itself):

```
# vim test.sh
#!/bin/ksh
echo $(pgrep -f $1)


# ./test.sh konakart
4676 17847
```

What is wrong on these lines?

Comment: Do you really need `-f/--full`?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to me: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results

Comment: Also, not a bash script ... this is a korn shell script as denoted by #!/bin/ksh

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi: I need the full output because it runs via jvm

Comment: @charlie_pl I want to use pgrep, because it only returns the PID, not the whole information to the process

Comment: @Inian didn't worked - ntohing showed up

Comment: @fourtyfour pgrep accepts regex too, just try it out, replacing grep with pgrep

Comment: @grail - makes that a difference for using that command?

Comment: @charlie_pl I tried that before. But pgrep piped on ps aux returned nothing.

My problem maybe is with the argument $1:
When I replace $1 with konakart directly, it returns only the one value I wanted.

Comment: @fortyfour - no it won't make a difference to the commands output, but you have shown users one thing and said it was something different.  A more complicated script it may well make a difference as both languages do not support all of the same features and commands :)

Answer (score 1):

You have not considered your command that you entered at the command line.

When submitted at the command line, you are correct that there is only a single command running with the word konakart in its full description.

Now you are calling a script ... how??

```
./test.sh konakart
```

So now how many commands have the word konakart in their full listing?

the answer is 2, the one you think you are looking for and the one you just submitted where you put the word on the command line to call your script ;)

Comment: thats right. I just mentioned that in my last comment. But how is that possible to remove this from my search? Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably need to advise of the big picture?  The short answer is you can then use a second normal grep with -v option to ignore your test.sh

Comment: Thank you for that hint:
I now use:
echo $(pgrep -fl $1 | grep -v test.sh)
And the only thing is to "remove" the processname.

Comment: I would also query why you are bothering with the echo?  You might also want to look u the other options available to pgrep to see if they might have a better solution.  As said before, without knowing your actual script requirement that's about as much as we can help :)

Comment: I want to use it to check if a process is running (for a check on icinga).
To do this with different processes I pass different parameters.

The full code I pasted (for formatting reasons) as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned (in grails answer) here is my check-snipped for icinga:

```
# vim check_process
#!/bin/ksh
rc=0
#kkPID=$(pgrep -f konakart)
#kkPID=$(ps -ef | awk '/[k]onakart/{print $2}')
#kkPID=$(ps -eo pid,command | grep "konakart" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}')
pid=$(pgrep -fl $1 | grep -v "check_process" | sed "s/\(\d*\) .*/\1/")
if [ -z "$pid" ]
then
  msg="CRITICAL - No $1 process found"
  rc=2
else
  msg="OK - $1 runs on PID: $pid"
fi
echo $msg
return $rc
```

Comment: Well depending on whether or not you know there may be only one of your processes running, you could use pgrep -fo "$1" or if you know that the process you are looking for is the only item, you could look at the -x option